# Showing Addresses in a Map

Tags: google-maps

I'm looking for an online map which can show many adresses in the same time. And with many I mean nearly 1000. 
At first I thought of Google Maps, but afaik this has a limit of under 100, so this is no solution. Does anybody know an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if Google limits the number of markers, but I think first your browser will slow down to a crawl if you try this. Also 1000 markers on a map will give a terrible user experience.

A common approach to this problem is Clustering. Basically you display only a part of the markers based on their proximity and the zoom level you are using. An example would be the [MarkerManager](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/docs/examples.html). However in larger setups with a larger number of markers it is common to query a server-side API via AJAX with the boundaries of your viewport and get the positions of the markers inside the viewport back in return.